# Problem with Flash...help

Tags: flash, flash-cs4

Hey Guys...need help.  Working on a project and get this error on the Output Log

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
>       at FlashSite_fla::MainTimeline/frame16()

Here's every frame that is on, begins, or crosses frame 16

> Layer Name: Top Menu (4 Button named Home_btn, Works_btn, Tech_btn, Contact_btn)
>   Code attached to frame: 
>   stop();
>   Home_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, home);
>   function home(event:MouseEvent):void {
>       gotoAndStop(16); 
>   }
>   Works_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, works);
>   function works(event:MouseEvent):void {
>       gotoAndStop(17);
>   }
>   Tech_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tech);
>   function tech(event:MouseEvent):void {
>       gotoAndStop(18);
>   }
>   Contacts_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, contact);
>   function contact(event:MouseEvent):void {
>       gotoAndStop(19);
>   }
>   Layer Name: Investment Opp (button named Invest_btn)
>   Code attached to frame:
>   Invest_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, invest);
>   function invest(event:MouseEvent):void {
>       var link:URLRequest = new URLRequest('#');
>       navigateToURL(link);
>   }
>   Layer Name: MfgOpp (Button named Mfg_btn)
>   Code attached to frame:
>   Mfg_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mfg);
>   function mfg(event:MouseEvent):void {
>       var link:URLRequest = new URLRequest('#');
>       navigateToURL(link);
>   }
>   Layer Name: MarketResearch (button name Own_btn)
>   Code attached to frame:
>   Own_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, own);
>   function own(event:MouseEvent):void {
>       var link:URLRequest = new URLRequest('#');
>       navigateToURL(link);
>   }
>   Layer Name: ActionScript
>   Code attached to frame:
>   import flash.events.MouseEvent;

What am I doing wrong?!?!

Comment: SOLVED!

By the way, did anyone know that you don't have to hard-code the buttons anymore.  You can, and most of mine work, but when you have the Item Highlighted...under Properties->Option it has a LINK field and a Target field...set those and the three that didn't work, worked!

Comment: UNSOLVED! Only works with TEXT-BASED buttons that link to an external link.  But for some reason the one that links to another frame, doesn't work properly...same error: 1009.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not familiar to fash cs4 but as for prevois version 
imports where done in the same layer:
move `import flash.events.MouseEvent;` to where `Mfg_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mfg);` is 
or just try all code in one layer, with `'import flash.events.MouseEvent;'`   beeing first

Comment: Okay...so, all the buttons for the above code work perfectly for the Menu...however the 3 listed on the bottom are not working at all.  They are viewed as a button, but not functioning...not directing the click to provided link (I know my example is using # as the url, but I've changed it to the appropriate page) DON"T KNOW WHAT"S WRONG!

Comment: sorry, can't install cs4. currently bussy with my own projects. if problem remains untill when i'm done will set up and try to figure out. by the way in flash 8 i had some unhandleable bug and "got out" copying content in new file... the code was 100% working...

as for what i can say... use debug or setp by step creation and tacing if flash know what to handle...
for example i whould try from start..            
ActionScript creation\trace\adding a behavior\trace\inside behavoir\trace\and testing a funtion...